# How to run a twitter app from a browser extension with user-context?

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth, browser-extension

I wish to make a twitter app that runs locally from a browser extension that uses user-context. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: You can load the Twitter web page in an IFRAME on click of browser action button.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This would reload the iframe in each open tab though, right?

Comment: It would automatically reload on other tabs. Suppose user initiates it on tab 1 and after sometime switches to tab 2. The IFRAME wont be available on tab 2. User has to initiate the IFRAME again for tab 2.

Comment: I see, thank you. But that is not exactly what I am trying to achieve, I am going for something that will act like a sidebar of one's twitter feed, and constantly display it no matter the tab. I feel as though the IFRAME route might be a bit resource intensive. I think this might be achievable on firefox, but I'm not sure about other browsers.